# How to make this arc?

Tags: android, xml, view

I try create this view:

[image: How to make this arc?]

I do not know how to make an arc with line. I tried some `shape` and attribute `radius` but doesn't work.

Comment: make a custom `View` and do your drawing inside `onDraw` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create semicircle of your view like this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:clipOrientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom">
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#444"/>
</shape>
```